# FsReveal and XPlot.Plotly: embed a plot in an FsReveal Presentation

Tags: f#, markdown

I'm trying to include an plot generated with `XPlot.Plotly` in a presentation created with the `F#` package `FsReveal`.  I can simply get the presentation up and running with a `.fsx` file:

```
(**
- title : Testing FsReveal 
- description : Testing FsReveal
- author : You
- theme : moon
- transition : none
***
### Syntax Highlighting
#### F# (with tooltips)
*)

#r "../packages/XPlot.Plotly/lib/net45/XPlot.Plotly.dll"
open XPlot.Plotly
let scatter = 
    Scatter(
        x = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5], 
        y = [1.5; 1.; 1.3; 0.7; 0.8; 0.9],
        mode = "markers"
    )
let layout = 
    Layout(
        showlegend = false, 
        title = "Here's a test!"
    )
let data = seq [scatter]
let aPlot = Plotly.Plot(data, layout)
(**

***
## Literate Slides with FsReveal

<br />
FsReveal may embed the chart here:
*)  
aPlot.Show()
```

but the final `aPlot.Show()` statement only opens the plot `aPlot` in a new window in my browser.

**How can I embed the plot in the slide itself?**

The only work around I can see right now is to use `aPlot.Show()` to see the image in a browser window, save the plot as a `.png`, then reference the plot in the `.fsx` file, but this seems particularly cumbersome.  Is there an easier way to include a Plotly plot in an FsReveal presentation?

I don't need the "interactiveness" of the Plotly plot, but I like the ability to control what the plot looks like, thus my use of Plotly in F#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did have an example of embedding charts in FsReveal in my literate programming talk. This is a bit older and I think FsReveal might have changed a bit, but the key trick should be the same.

To embed a chart, you need to add [a few special commented commands](https://github.com/tpetricek/Talks/blob/master/2015/literate-programming/krakow/slides/sample.fsx#L216):

```
(**
## Slide with code sample
*)
(*** define-output:chart ***)
Chart.Line [ for x in 0.0 .. 10.0 -> x, sin x ]
(**
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Slide with output
*)
(*** include-it:chart ***)
```

There is a bit of documentation on how the [embedding works on F# Formatting web](https://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/evaluation.html).

The other part that it needs is to setup the FSI evaluator in `build.fsx`. You need the [line that calls `wrapFsiEvaluator` here](https://github.com/tpetricek/Talks/blob/master/2015/literate-programming/krakow/build.fsx#L21) (the talk had some stuff related to `ToHtml` method, which was for something else and  you do not need it).